# How to fix conflicting AbortSignal in node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts and node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts in Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Error: node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts:72:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'AbortSignal' must be of type '{ new (): AbortSignal; prototype: AbortSignal; abort(reason?: any): AbortSignal; timeout(milliseconds: number): AbortSignal; }', but here has type '{ new (): AbortSignal; prototype: AbortSignal; timeout(milliseconds: number): AbortSignal; }'.

72 declare var AbortSignal: {

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:2071:13
2071 declare var AbortSignal: {

'AbortSignal' was also declared here.

[image]

Comment: I just hit this issue too, in a Vue and typescript project. Hopefully someone will answer! Or did you figure out how to fix it?

Answer (score 74):

I added the latest @types/node to my project to force it to look for an updated version, and that resolved it for me.

```
npm i -D @types/node@latest
```

Comment: If I'm not on the latest version of Node, should I still install the latest version of @types/node?